# Tool/language/libraries to compose HTML-snippets into a new HTML page

Tags: html, parsing, dom, xpath, xhtml

I am regularly following (i.e. reading almost entirely) an online magazine, which to my dismay does not provide any suitable view for linear reading (like e.g. a printer-friendly view) but only a page containing a table of content (an HTML list containing links to each chapter) which one then needs to click on individually and - after reading the child-page - the back button again to return to the TOC.

I find the manual traversal of such a tree increasingly cumbersome (and also very slow due to the surrounding overhead that is loaded with each child page). I am thus considering to program me some tool or script that traverses that table of content automatically, loads each child page, extracts the relevant content and concatenates it, i.e. composes essentially a single linear "page" or HTML-document containing the entire magazine's content, so one could conveniently and linearly read it (or maybe even print it...).

I have analyzed the involved HTML pages a bit and in my opinion it should be possible to locate the table of contents with all the links and the content sections of the child-pages using a few carefully crafted XPATH-expressions, since all the relevant pieces are contained in <div ...>-elements with specific names or rather class attributes.

My first questions thus: does such a tool maybe already exist that one could parameterize accordingly to do such a table of content-based tree-traversal, extraction and concatenation? I googled quite a bit but couldn't find anything ready-made.

Assuming there is no such tool my second question is: what would be a suitable approach to implement such a tool? Clearly one would need to parse many HTML pages, locate specific -elements within them and extract and concatenate the located HTML-fragments into a new document.

What computer language would be best suited to do that job? I am a Java programmer by profession, but doing all that XML-parsing and text-fiddling in Java seems not very elegant to me. I could imagine that there are programming languages out there that are much more elegant and better suited for this kind of task. Suggestions?

Or last: if Java is indeed a reasonable choice for this task: what easy-to-use and robust libraries are there to parse essentially arbitrary HTML pages into a DOM, such that an XPATH-processor can then operate on it? 
All XML-parsers that I have worked with so far, would require me to first specify a full and robust schema before they would allow me to process arbitrary (X)HTML pages. I fancy that creating such a schema would already be a formidable task in itself. Is there some HTML-parser out there that can create a suitable DOM without the need to create such a schema?

Or any other suggestions how to approach or solve this problem?

Hope I could make myself clear...

Comment: As you mention Java, there are at least two HTML parser implementations available that don't require any schema to be defined: https://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/ and http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/tagsoup/.

Answer (score 0):

It is a general question. I will try to give you some advice(opinion based) even not having access to the website you are talking about.

To tackle your issue I would make usage of python since there are many libraries which let you automatize the scraping and the re-formatting of the contents.

Some advices:

- Have a look at: [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), [Beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and all tools/libraries in [web-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) on SO.
- You can change the approach with a visual scraper. An example is  [portia](https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia)